# WCF REST 4.0 ,not accessible

Tags: wcf, rest

I have created a WCF REST web service with no SVC and successfully deployed on IIS7.5 ,Win2008 server box .
I can access the service URL http://172.29.132.209:9999/TestService/CheckGet/sdfsds/response.xml from the Server machine ..using both ServerName ,Server Ip or localhost .It works .
But when i try this URL on client machine , it does not work I.E says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

What could be the potential isssue .?pls. help

Comment: none of them works on client machine -http://172.29.132.209:9999/TestService or http://172.29.132.209:9999/

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CheckGet/{testData}/response.xml", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        RetData CheckGetXML(string testData);

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things. Try it in a proper browser like firefox then stick fiddler up and see what the traffic looks like.

Comment: Is there any other option to bring out the issue ?

Comment: You could impliment a message inspector class to log exactly what is coming in and out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx